# How to fix git commit with atom text editor

Tags: git, terminal, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I have a problem when committing a file with atom text editor

I've used in **Git Bash**

`git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"`

but when committing a file like this:

`git commit`

This error show up:

`hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 'C:\Users\SALAH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

`Aborting commit due to empty commit message.`

[image]

---

but when using sublime text as my text editor like this:
`git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe' -n -w"`

the commitment works perfectly

it is a problem with **atom** or something about the PATH...

---

any suggestions I will be thankful

Answer (score 1):

I also had the similar issue then I figured out that I have a space in my username between two words.

Git directs to the path but stops right before the space in username ('C:\Users\SALAH') and throws the following error -

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 'C:\Users\SALAH' is not 
recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

Solution = Change your username to one word or without spaces. You can follow this particular video to change your username without reinstalling windows.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_rTOA4gXJI

Answer (score 1):

In the line;

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

Replace "atom" with the direct path to the atom application. Surround the path with single quotes.

Eg;

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.53.0\atom.exe' --wait"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the real path of atom.exe.

My command looked like this:

`$ git config --global core.editor "C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/atom/atom.exe"`

It worked for me. You can also give it a try.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1. Find you `.gitconfig` file. It's possibly under `C:\Users\Username\.gitconfig`.
2. Edit the parameter `core.editor`. Add **SINGLE QUOTES** to both sides of what's behind `editor=` which is the path of your text editor.

In my case, the original file is like

```
[core]
    editor = C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text\\sublime_text.exe
```

You should change it to

```
[core]
    editor = 'C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text\\sublime_text.exe'
```

---

The issue is probably caused by the space in the path of your editor. I met the similar issue as follow:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... C:\Program Files\Sublime Text\sublime_text.exe: line 1: C:Program: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text\sublime_text.exe'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

The usage of `git commit` without a `-m` or `-F` parameter will make git call for the text editor to edit the commit message. The calling process is made with cmd while it cannot figure the space in the filepath without a quote. Therefore the issue is solved this way.