# VS Code Git (Extension) errors and displays COMMIT_EDITMSG

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am trying to commit changes in VSCode using the Git extension, but suddenly, when I try to commit from VS Code using the Git extension, I receive an error that prevents me from committing that says:

> Commit operation was cancelled due to empty commit message.

However, I am never provided with the opportunity to provide a commit message, as I have previously been able to do. I am able to commit normally through the MacOS terminal, so it appears to be a VSCode specific issue.

A file called `COMMIT_EDITMSG` pops up instead. Any ideas for how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is your goal to be able the commit message in the terminal? or is the answer simply "write the commit message in that `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file and then save and close it? I usually use git outside of vscode, but that seems to be what the name implies

Comment: I'm simply trying to commit changes using the VSCode git extension, but this error is preventing me from doing so. Thanks for the clarifying question -- I've updated the question to reflect.

Comment: Ah, so that error appears even while that `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file is still open. I didn't grasp that part, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue in VS Code navigating to:

Code > Preferences > Settings

and then searching for and unchecking "Git: Use Editor As Commit Input" as suggested here: [Why COMMIT_EDITMSG opens when i try to commit in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908270/why-commit-editmsg-opens-when-i-try-to-commit-in-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

When you run `git commit` from a bash or other shell session, Git invokes your editor-of-choice.<sup>1,2</sup>  Git then *waits for this editor to signal to Git that it is done*, after which Git reads the file that the editor presumably updated by this point.  But some editors *immediately signal that they are done*, and this is when the problem occurs.

If you are using such an editor, you have three choices:

- Switch to a different editor that is not so badly behaved.
- Find some way of running your favorite editor that tells it to behave better.  *Most* of these editors have an option, usually spelled `w` or `wait` or `--wait` or `-w` or something like that, to make them behave well for Git.<sup>3</sup>  See, e.g., [How to fix git commit with atom text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49054885/1256452).
- Use `git commit` such that it always has a prepared commit message (`git commit -m`, `git commit -F`, and the like).  This is probably the worst method, though.

For VSCode specifically, see [How to use Visual Studio Code as default editor for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30024353/1256452), but note that VSCode is *complicated* and not all of the extensions for it play nice.  That's probably why there are more than a dozen answers to this question.

---

<sup>1</sup>Run `git var GIT_EDITOR` to see what your choice is.  Use any of `core.editor` as a `git config` setting, or `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` or `$GIT_EDITOR` as an environment variable, to *change* the setting.  See [the `git var` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var) for more about how Git picks *which* setting to use if you provide multiple settings.

<sup>2</sup>More precisely, `git commit` looks to see if it's been provided a "pre-cooked" commit message, and it can use that directly without having to invoke your editor-of-choice.  But this problem only comes up when it's using your editor and waiting for it.

<sup>3</sup>Their behavior is actually fine for certain GUIs, and these editors were written with those GUIs in mind.  It's just *bad for Git*.